# sqlworkbench-j not closing transaction connection

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I am using sqlworkbench-j to query Redshift data. I am facing issue of locking tables whenever I do query on this table. It also happens for simple select statements. I know this is happening because workbench explicitly adds `begin` for every statement to take care for any changes happening for the data. So for every query we need to write `end transaction`.

Is there any option to disable the `begin` statement or to add `end transaction` statement in sqlworkbench-j?

Answer (score 2):

When you set up redshift - click the "autocommit" option.
see here for more detailed instructions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html

especially point 10